# How do I recursively generate documentation of an entire project with pydoc?

Tags: python-3.x, pydoc

I have a python project inside a specific folder named "Project 1". I want to extract all the docstrings of all the python files inside this project.

In this project all the modules are imported dynamically through `__init__.py` and, for that reason, when I run pydoc it fails on the imports.

Comment: No chance you still have the error message, but without the actual error message, I'm going to give a generic answer here.

Answer (score 0):

`python -m pydoc -w module_folder/` will work for some scenarios, but not all. For example, if you want to document modules and submodules of an installed package, it won't work, you'd need to pivot to a different tool.

Using your favorite language you will need to:

1. Iterate through files in your target folder
2. Call pydoc once per (sub)module

[Here is one of many examples on Github](https://github.com/andreww5au/PaSD-client/blob/4ea5fac6cb6b00e3aabad09a2974e0fd9b2ef949/gendocs.py).

Pdoc, pydoctor both handle walking folders automatically, [my fork of pydoc walks the module dependency tree by default.](https://github.com/matthewdeanmartin/pydoc_fork)